# What does +___% to find gold/magic items give?

Tags: torchlight-2

Some of my gear says it gives +__% to finding gold and magic items. What exactly does this mean? Does it mean for gold I'm more likely to:

- Find more gold piles in general laying on the ground (natural spawns)?
- Find more gold in each pile?
- Increase the chances of finding more gold piles from killed mobs/chests/destroyables?

As for magic items, does it mean I'm more likely to:

- Find better gear? like greens instead of whites? blues instead of greens? etc
- Increase chance for gear to drop from a kill/chest/destroyable?

Comment: I can't speak for gold, but for magic find it's the standard 2: 1) you will find better tiers of gear (greens instead of whites, etc.) and 2) you will find better gear drops from *everything*, including mobs, chests, destructibles, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For gold:

- +_% amount of gold found means you get more gold when it drops, it doesn't affect gold drop rates.

For items:

- +_% magic finding means increased drop rate for gear, but not necessarily yields better gear. Each item tier (green, blue, yellow, purple) has its own drop rates (%), and it is this drop rate that will be increased.

Comment: That's good info but is there any sources to this or is it just personal experience? Either is ok with me